# Is DataSnap an appropriate solution to bring the data and business logic of an existing Windows app to mobile/web clients?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I need to take a huge Delphi XE application (backed by proprietary SQL server NexusDB) and begin providing my clients the ability to access the system in new ways:

- Thinner Windows client for slow/VPN connections
- Mobile/Tablet
- Web

DataSnap appropriate for this or is introducing a middle tier the wrong way about providing remote/mobile access?  Other solutions/ideas welcome.

(I have XE2 Enterprise but am stuck on XE Enterprise for awhile.)

Comment: Does the system run on the end-users computer? For a multi-tier architecture, the application needs an application server which the mobile / tablet / web browser can connect to.

Comment: Nexus installs on their server PC if they have it, otherwise a random Windows PC.  DS server would go with the Nexus SQL server.  This means for mobile/tablet access the datasnap server needs exposed to the public which may be an issue per ldsandon's below post regrading security.

Comment: @Richard, it sounds like there is no middle tier now, is that correct? Just client/server?

Comment: If you go with middle tier (and I think that's likely) look outside of the DataSnap box for options with better security. I use RemObjects DataAbstract & am very happy, but there is also kbmmw.

Comment: @MarcusAdams No middle tier yet

Comment: Do you want to do all of the client development or do you want to open it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSnap is being aggressively positioned by Embarcadero as a Multi-platform connectivity solution, where servers are written in Delphi, and mobile connectors are available (in XE2 and later) for a variety of mobile device platforms. So the quick answer is yes, it is suitable in general.

Is it suitable for you? You haven't said much that would help me answer that question; You are willing to buy Enterprise or Architect SKUs of Delphi, so I would guess yes.

If it was me, I'd look for a solution that implements a pure simple REST architecture that is available to every system out there, mobile or otherwise, no matter what language or platform, but I haven't got a suggested alternative because it seems to me that SOAP is nearly dead and that there is no universal replacement technology out there that does everything that soap client/server systems do.  I'd be tempted to consider "roll your own REST+json" or evaluate Remobject's product offerings too, and select a path that makes sense for you, from a business and technical point of view.

Datasnap is fine, but it's not the only option.  It's probably the simplest and most easy to roll out option currently available, and the only one "out of box" ready to go in XE2 if you want apple, android, and a few others, right away.

Comment: REST is one of the worst RPC architecture I've ever seen. It's a symptom of how "the whole web is a string" concept has brainwashed developers since people started to code in Javascript.

Comment: I think REST is pretty easy to work with - I'm not sure about brainwashing?  I've always found SOAP to be terrible to work with in comparison.

Comment: REST is a joy compared to SOAP, which is a crap.  REST is "worst" the way that C/C++ are "worst" to a LISP/Smalltalk person.  That is, the design emphasizes things that don't matter to you if you're a design idealist instead of a trench-warfare veteran pragmatist. Do the simplest thing that could possibly work (repeatably, universally, portably) and you end up with a requirement for Idempotence, strings (versus byte order issues), and the REST (ha ha ha) is history.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your security needs, and the way you're providing data to clients. As I often pointed out, dbExpress-Datasnap has big security flaws (while the DCOM version is not well suited outside a LAN, and does not offer out of the box mobile devices support).

A web application would have less issues because the datasnap-web server connection would be probaby internal, it would be up to the web application to ensure data protection.

Comment: The glaring issue is the fact that this is a retail software package and not an application for a single customer.  Some users will want this public facing where security is a concern.  Imagine selling a software package to thousands of customers over the years who now expect mobile/remote/web/whatever access with good security and performance.

Comment: @Richard in that case add an TIdHttpServer and WebBrokerBridge to your server application and construct a RESTful interface on top of that. Marco Cantu has plenty of REST examples to get you started on a proof of concept.

Comment: If HTTPS (with a proper setup) is enough for your needs Datasnap could be a choice. Thet TCP connection is much weaker from a security point of view. I understand perfectly your expectations, it was a pity that Datasnap was designed with database stored procedure calls in mind, and not as a sound RPC library that could work in an 'hostile' environment across a connection you may not control end to end.

Comment: Proper setup?  Up to date Open SSL, etc?

Comment: Right, proper certificate chain setup, proper web server setup, up-tp-date libraries, ecc. ecc. HTTPS also allows for client authentication, if needed, but that requires of course a certificate enrollment system. More or less, HTTPS is as much as safe as its certificates are. The recent compromises of CAs shows one of the weakest points. That's why, for example, self-signed certificates may be very unsecure, really no way to tell they are valid ones, everybody can fake one.